# Power Query M - flexible delete of Columns

Tags: powerquery, m

I read some Power Query sources and some Columns are empty but I don't know which ones.
How can I dynamicly delete the first, second, third,... Column without entries?

The advanced challenge is, that I even don't know how many columns are available.
How can I perform something like a loop as
For x = 1 to Columns.Count
  if col(x) is empty than delete col(x)

I'm looking foreward to see your responses, thanks a lot.

Kind regards
Jens

Answer (score 1):

You can use this function, which selects a list of headers containing any value in the entire column, and returns only those columns:

```
(MyTable) =>
let
    Headers = Table.ColumnNames(MyTable),
    Output = Table.SelectColumns(MyTable, List.Select(Headers, each List.MatchesAny(Table.Column(MyTable, _), each _ <> null)))
in
    Output
```